# Since I Type ''mvn -version'' This shows up to me

Tags: maven

When I type "mvn -version" in CMD and this show up to me.
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Users\acer\Desktop\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin

How To Solve This?? Hope Guys can help me out.

Comment: I don't know how do this , please help :( I'm just a kid

Comment: There is something terribly broken ... you are on Windows, right? Please reinstall Maven and then make sure that you properly added it to your path variable.

Comment: Oh.. That Fixed.. Thanks JF Meier. Have a good weekend :D